# Dojo grid inside titlePane not getting painted until the browser is resized

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have an dojo enhanced grid inside a title pane which inturn in Tabcontainer. I am creating a tab container dynamically and painting the title pane which contains grid. For the first time the grid is painted properly but if i close the tab and again try it to open a tabcontainer title pane is painted but grid inside the titlepane is not painted (or rather its not visible) until i do a browser resize.
So anybody have faced similar kind of issue? Please let me know the solution for this.
I tried resize(), update() &  startup() methods on grid nothing worked out.

I am kind of stuck please share your thoughts on this.

Thanks,
Vikram

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a workaround by doing a dojo connect like:

```
dojo.connect(Datagrid,"_onFetchComplete",DataGrid,"_resize");
```

So it should automatically be resized, when DataGrid finished loading data.

Hope I could help.

Greeting, Simon

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks.. Will try this solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting an absolute height on the Grid?
Which browsers did you try? (I experienced various problems with DataGrid in TabCointainer using IE)

Comment: Thanks Simon.. By setting an absolute height resolves my issue. But i want to the grid to dynamically calculate the height. As of now i go with setting height. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

You must call the `TabContainer.layout()` each time its container is changing size. For doing this, you could 1) monitor DOMEvents onunderflow and onoverflow on containing DOMNode or 2) when container becomes visible (once-n-forall).

Reason why a window.onresize event fixes it is, that the TabContainer hooks on said event and calls its own layout.

In your situation, where the TabController fiddles with TabContainer's panes, there may be missing a 'layoutChildren' somewhere. Optimally, you should place the grid as the first on only child to tab.

After the grid is deployed, it will take an absolute, calculated height - 'inherited' from the TabContainer. This is fired once the TabContainer chooses to resize or instructed to do so.

Manually, you should be able to implement these lines - after re-opening a tab. The script is taken from _Grid.js to illustrate

```
var grid = dijit.byId('MYGRIDID');
require(["dijit/layout/utils"], function(layerUtils) {
   layoutUtils.layoutChildren(grid.domNode,
               grid._contentBox, 
              [grid.tablist, {
                  domNode: grid.tablistSpacer,
                  layoutAlign: titleAlign
              }, {
                  domNode: grid.containerNode,
                  layoutAlign: "client"
              }]);
   grid._containerContentBox = layoutUtils.marginBox2contentBox(grid.containerNode,
              {
                  domNode: grid.containerNode,
                  layoutAlign: "client"
              });
   // note this line in particular
   grid.selectedChildWidget.resize(grid._containerContentBox);
}
```

Comment: if you need a quick patch, something like `grid.selectedChildWidget.resize(dojo.coords(grid.containerNode));` might do the trick

Answer (score 0):

### My issue

I had a *similar* situation as yours:

- Grid is in a titlepane (closed by default).
- Grid can be destroyed and re-created on the fly.
- Issue appears when user:

  1. opens the pane.
  2. closes the pane.
  3. re-creates the grid.
  4. re-opens the pane.
  5. **grid is not visible, until browser window is resized!**

### My solution

My approach was to force a `resize()` on my grid whenever the title pane was being opened.
I used code like this, in a place where I had access to both the grid and the panes:

```
var titlePane = registry.byId("title-pane-id");
var handle = aspect.after(titlePane, "toggle", function(deferred) {
    if (titlePane.open) {
        grid.resize();
    }
});
```

- [The dojo/aspect doc](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/aspect.html)
- Don't forget to [remove the aspect from your grid](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/on.html#removing-an-event-handler) if you destroy it.
- I did this on dojo v1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

My solution is too easy: define on declaration of grid the bold parameter write here:

```
grid = new EnhancedGrid({id: 'MyIDgrid',
store: dataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: myStore}),
        structure: structureGrid,
        plugins: pluginGrid,
        style : 'width: 725px; height: 350px',
        autoWidth : true,
**autoHeight : false,height:'200px',**
        elasticView : '2'
}, document.createElement('div'));
```

this resolve all!
Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

`style="height: auto;"` will fit the purpose.